# ValueError: time data does not match format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm using Python 3.6.

I'm having an issue with reformatting dates. My code is currently processing 610 dates, but the code throws a Value Error on dates containing the month of August.

**ERROR:time data 'Augu 30, 2017' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'**

Here's the HTML string that my code is trying to reformat.

```
 <td>
   <div class="date">
     <span data-date-format="MMMM Do, YYYY" data-date-value="2017-08-30T16:04:39.3+00:00" data-hook="datetime">August 30th, 2017</span>
   </div>
 </td>
```

The date in this string is *August 30th, 2017*, so what is causing the Value Error?

Here's my code:

```
publishedDateFormat = table.find('div', {'class': 'date'})
for date in publishedDateFormat.find('span'):
   cleanDate = date.replace('nd', '').replace('rd', '').replace('st', '').replace('th', '')
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
   publishedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(cleanDate, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%m%d%Y')
   list_of_cells.append(publishedDate)
```

Comment: The error clearly shows that the string isn't "August". You're replacing `st` and ending up with "Augu"

Comment: Yes, the Value Error states that the string isn't "August," but the HTML clearly shows that the string is "August."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is causing the issue is:

```
cleanDate = date.replace('nd', '').replace('rd', '').replace('st', '').replace('th', '')
```

You are getting rid of the `"st"` from `"August"`.

I would recommend using regex (or some other means) to check if the character immediately preceding it is a digit (`[0-9]`).

Example of regex:

```
cleandate = re.sub('([0-9])(nd|rd|st|th)' , '\g<1>', date)
```

Comment: does this look right?  cleanDate = re.sub('[0-9]nd|rd|st|th' , '', date)

Comment: Not quite - I've updated the answer to include the regex

Comment: For some reason this regex is striping the day from some of the dates: 
January 1st , 2017, becomes January , 2017

Comment: I wasted hours trying to solve this issue yesterday and you helped me fix the issue in minutes!!   THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
cleanDate = date.replace('nd', '').replace('rd', '').replace('st', '').replace('th', '')
```

replace('st', '') is changing August to Augu, which is causing the error.

Kindly correct your formating.

Use regex to collect the date fields and then create a cleanDate object as following:-

```
import re, locale, datetime

# considering dateString is the string representation of Date from Text
dateString = 'August 30th, 2017'
dateValues = re.search(r'(\w+)[\s](\d+)[A-Za-z\s,]*(\d+)', dateString)
if dateValues:
    cleanDate = dateValues.groups(0)[0]+' '+dateValues.groups(0)[1]+', '+dateValues.groups(0)[2]
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
    publishedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(cleanDate, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%m%d%Y')
    print publishedDate
```